# GridBagLayout (the same line)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

In my program user must initially select the number of rooms and then number of adults and children for each room. If number of children more than 0 a user must input their ages. As a layout I use GridBagLayout but I do not understand how to locate these comboboxes with ages at the same line as combobox with children number. Can somebody advise me something in this case?

```
public class Selection extends JFrame {
    JLabel rooms;
    JComboBox r;
    public Selection() {
        final GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(gbl);
        final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        rooms = new JLabel("Rooms:");
        String[] x = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        r = new JComboBox(x);
        r.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        r.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            JComboBox[] adults;
            JComboBox[] children;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                c.gridheight = 1;
                c.gridwidth = 1;
                c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
                c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                remove(r);
                remove(rooms);
                String[] str = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
                String[] str1 = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
                final String[] str2 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"};
                adults = new JComboBox[5];
                children = new JComboBox[5];
                final JComboBox[] ages = new JComboBox[5];
                final JLabel[] adultLabels = new JLabel[5];
                JLabel[] childrenLabels = new JLabel[5];
                final JLabel[] ageLabels = new JLabel[5];

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    adultLabels[i] = new JLabel("Adults in room " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    childrenLabels[i] = new JLabel("Children in room " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    adults[i] = new JComboBox(str);
                    adults[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    children[i] = new JComboBox(str1);
                    children[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    final int finalI = i;
                    children[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            int h = 0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < children[finalI].getSelectedIndex(); j++) {
                                h += 2;
                                ageLabels[j] = new JLabel("Age " + (j + 1) + ":");
                                ages[j] = new JComboBox(str2);
                                ages[j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                                c.gridx = 8;
                                c.gridy = h;
                                gbl.setConstraints(ageLabels[j], c);
                                add(ageLabels[j]);
                                //c.gridx = 7;
                                gbl.setConstraints(ages[j], c);
                                add(ages[j]);
                            }
                            getContentPane().validate();
                        }
                    });
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= r.getSelectedIndex(); i++) {
                    c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                    gbl.setConstraints(adultLabels[i], c);
                    add(adultLabels[i]);
                    gbl.setConstraints(adults[i], c);
                    add(adults[i]);
                    gbl.setConstraints(childrenLabels[i], c);
                    add(childrenLabels[i]);
                    gbl.setConstraints(children[i], c);
                    add(children[i]);
                }
                getContentPane().validate();
            }
        });

        gbl.setConstraints(rooms, c);
        add(rooms);
        gbl.setConstraints(r, c);
        add(r);

    }
    }
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame selection = new Selection();
                selection.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                selection.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                selection.setVisible(true);
                selection.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL; .. c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` Wait .. what? I suspect that's two different kinds of SNAFU, but have not finished my first coffee of the day (so can't trust what I think on first look).

Comment: From an ergomic point of view, I would use a wizard, to separate the differents steps. It would be more clear for the user, and easier to code :-)